# Syntax error; token: ":number", near: "in :number"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get data from AWS DynamoDB table with boto3 client.

```
filter_expression = "A1 = :a"
expression_attribute_values = {":a" : {"S":"8"}}

if _numbers:
    filter_expression = "{} and {}".format(
        filter_expression, "Number in :number"
    )
    expression_attribute_values[":number"] = {"SS": _numbers}

search_query = {
    "TableName": XXXXXXXXXXX,
    "FilterExpression": filter_expression,
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": expression_attribute_values,
}
if LastEvaluatedKey:
    search_query["ExclusiveStartKey"] = LastEvaluatedKey

response = client.scan(**search_query)
```

I'm facing the ValidationException issue.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: ":number", near: "in :number"
```

- query `IN` is making an issue.
- tried `L` & `NS` not working

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you.

print(search_query)

`{'TableName': 'XXXXXXX', 'FilterExpression': 'A1 = :a AND Number IN :number', 'ExpressionAttributeValues': {':a': {'S': '20'}, ':number': {'NS': ['200', '77']}}}`

Comment: Can you post `print(search_query)` to actually see how it looks like?

Comment: thank you @marcin for the reply & added print message

Comment: Are you sure the `IN :number` is correct? Shouldn't it be `AND Number IN (200, 77)` or similar ? The correct [syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html) seems to be `a IN (b, c, d)`